# Finding the vector potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, differentiation, vector-fields

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}\right)=\nabla\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}\right)-\nabla^2\mathbf{A}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}\tag{5.62}$$

Whenever I try to work this out and prove the second equality, I get the a plus sign rather than a subtraction. Can someone show me how the derivative squared of $A$ is negative and not positive?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to write the curl as the tensor product,
$$\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{u}\right)_k=\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_iu_j$$
Since $\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$ is also a vector, let this be the $u_j$ in the above:
\begin{align}
\left(\nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}\right)\right)_k&=\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_i\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}\right)_j \\
&=\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_i\left(\varepsilon_{lmj}\partial_lA_m\right)\\
&=\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{lmj}\partial_i\partial_lA_m\tag{1}
\end{align}
It's here that we need to use the relation of the Levi-Civita symbol and the Kronecker Delta:
$$\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{lmj}=\delta_{im}\delta_{kl}-\delta_{il}\delta_{km}$$
Insertion of this into Eq (1),
$$\nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}\right)=\left(\delta_{im}\delta_{kl}-\delta_{il}\delta_{km}\right)\partial_i\partial_lA_m\tag{2}$$
Then it's just a matter of matching the indices:
$$\nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}\right)=\partial_m\partial_kA_m-\partial_l^2A_k=\nabla\left(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{A}\right)-\nabla^2\mathbf{A}$$

Comment: Your first two equations have vectors on the LHS and components on the RHS. For example, the first equation should read: $(\nabla \times \mathbf{u})_k = \epsilon_{ijk}\nabla_i u_j$

Comment: In the future, feel free to edit such inconsequential details into the post.

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian
$$
\nabla^2\mathbf A
=\begin{pmatrix}
\nabla^2A_x
\\
\nabla^2A_y
\\
\nabla^2A_z
\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{\partial^2\mathbf A}{\partial x^2}
+\frac{\partial^2\mathbf A}{\partial y^2}
+\frac{\partial^2\mathbf A}{\partial z^2}
$$

Per Wikipedia
$$
\nabla^2\mathbf A
=\nabla(\nabla\cdot\mathbf A)-\nabla\times(\nabla\times\mathbf A)
$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator

Comment: This isn't a proof, it's a restatement of the original equation but moving 1 term to the other side.

Answer (score 0):

That is just the vector identity, $\bf a\times(b\times c)=b(a\times c)-c(a\times b)$ for vectors, $\bf a,b,c$, chosen as $\nabla,\nabla,A$.  For each term, $\nabla$ acts twice on $\bf A$. The identity can be verified by putting in components.